# Moving the label for a tick mark

Tags: tikz-pgf

The label "ma + b" at the tick mark on the y-axis is to the left of the tick mark.  I want it to the right of the tick mark. (The command `extra y tick labels={$ma+b$,anchor=east}` didn't move the label.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}
\noindent\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-7,ymax=5.5,
    restrict y to domain=-7:5.5,
    %enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={-1},
    extra x tick labels={$a$},
    extra y ticks={-3},
    extra y tick labels={$ma+b$,anchor=east},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
%/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=101,domain=-2.5:3] {2*x - 1} node[right, pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize]{$y = mx + b$};
\draw [fill] (-1,-3) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The key-value pair `anchor=east` has no effect where you've placed it. This is because it is treated as the next element in the array `extra y tick labels`, but is never typeset because there is only one element (-3) in `extra y ticks`.

Also note that instead of `\hspace{\fill}` you can use `\hfill`. Or in this case, just use `\centering` once inside the group you want centered.

Anyway, here's one approach using `yticklabel style={anchor=west}` and `yticklabel shift=-4pt`. There are nicer keys to do this without manual positioning, but unfortunately they only work for the standard boxed axes. I also removed several unnecessary items from the MWE, and adjusted the position of the equation label so it is not truncated at the edge of the axis.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,samples=101,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-7,ymax=5.5,
    restrict y to domain=-7:5.5,
    %enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={-1},
    extra x tick labels={$a$},
    extra y ticks={-3},
    extra y tick labels={$ma+b$},
    yticklabel style={anchor=west},
    yticklabel shift=-4pt,
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
%/pgfplots/xlabel shift={10pt};
\addplot[latex-latex,samples=101,domain=-2.5:3] {2*x - 1} node[right, pos=0.65,font=\footnotesize]{$y = mx + b$};
\draw [fill] (-1,-3) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The location of the label of the tick mark is where I wanted it.  Why does TikZ typeset the label in the appropriate place with your code and not my code?  I see that in your code you have `yticklabel style={anchor=west},` following `extra y tick labels={$ma+b$},` and I put the location inside the braces.  Also, why does the location "west" put the tick mark in the appropriate place? Since "ma + b" is the the right of the y-axis, shouldn't the location be "east"?  Why did you need a vertical shift downward by 4mm?

Comment: @Adelyn the reason your code doesn't work is explained in the first paragraph of my answer. `anchor=west` is used because I want to position the tick label relative to its left (west) edge. The shift (it's a horizontal shift, not a vertical shift) is required to move the tick label to the other side of the axis. (By default, the anchor is placed on the left side of the axis, but in this case that causes the tick label to cover up part of the axis.)

Comment: Why does the "-4pt" in the command `yticklabel shift=-4pt` move the label "ma + b" horizontally rightward?  What is the command to move it rightward 4pt and upward 2pt?

Comment: @Adelyn the key `yticklabel shift` specifies the shift for the y-axis tick label. Because of the way `pgfplots` sets things up, giving a positive value would shift the label "away" from the default boxed axis style. On your axes, this corresponds to "left", so I gave a negative value (`-4pt`) to go the opposite direction (right). To add an upward shift of `2pt` to my solution, you could add `yshift=2pt` inside the value of the `yticklabel style` key.

Comment: I decided to move the label "y = mx + b" for the graph above the line. I tried using the positional values "above" and "left, above" for the `node` command; they gave me the label with the line drawn over it. The positional value "left" displayed it better. I would like it moved upward a bit so that the line is not drawn over (or too close to) the label.

Comment: @Adelyn `above` and `left, above` give exactly the same positioning, because in the second case, only the last position specification is used. The proper way to do it would be to use `above left`. But if you have questions about this, I think it's best to open a new question, since this question (and my answer) focus specifically on shifting the tick mark labels.